# ListView not updating when orientation changed

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, datagrid

I have a DataGrid added programmatically in my App. I have a event which is called when the MainDisplayInfo gets changed. In this event I call my function to create the grid.

```
Grid grid = this.dataGrid.Children[0] as Grid; // the header 
ContentView view = this.dataGrid.Children[1] as ContentView;
ListView lv = this.dataGrid.Children[2] as ListView;     // the body of the datagrid
lv.ItemsSource = null;
lv.ItemsSource = viewModel.Statistiks;
```

I'm adding my Header and my Columns like this:

```
foreach (var item in zip)
{
    if (IsPortrait)
    {
        cc.Add(new DataGridColumn() { Title = item.Headers, PropertyName = item.Tables, Width = GridLength.Star, HorizontalContentAlignment = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand });
    }
    else
        cc.Add(new DataGridColumn() { Title = item.Headers, PropertyName = item.Tables, Width = GridLength.Star, HorizontalContentAlignment = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand });
}
```

My Itemssource Collection looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<StatistikModel> statistiks;
public ObservableCollection<StatistikModel> Statistiks
{
    get { return statistiks; }
    set { statistiks = value; OnPropertyChanged("Statistiks"); }
}
```

But when the orientation gets changed only the Header changes correctly but not the listview.

Comment: The method of judging the horizontal and vertical screen is where it is written, and whether it is written in the method of monitoring the horizontal and vertical screen feedback.

Comment: What do you mean with that @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: You can show which need to be changed in listview when orientation changed.

Comment: The correct data was already in the listview. Just the columns were'nt added. I found a solution for now. I just remove the datagrid from the stacklayout and add it again. @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: Okey,glad to hear that ! You can share your solution in answer :)